# how to send data to a running process?

Tags: process, pygtk, communication

I wrote a simple text editor in pygtk and it works fine, my problem is with opening new files in new tabs when my program is running, something like notepad++ and many other text editors.

Suppose my program is running and I opened a simple text file in it, then I select a new file on my disk, right click on it, and then select my program to opens with, my goal is that this file opens on a new tab, in my running program, but what happens is, my program starts again as a new process.

Can I somehow communicate with my program process and send my new file for it, or is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use sockets.

This code will, when run, check to see if a socket is already listening. If so, it means another instance of the app is already running, so it just passes its first argument (filepath passed to it by the OS when you right-click-open it) to it and closes.

If no socket is listening, (no app open) it opens a socket and then runs the main GTK window. Any filepath sent by subsequent runs is displayed, and here you could open another tab.

CAVEAT: I don't use sockets often, so it is likely that some things have not been done 100% correctly, and may cause hangs.

Look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) for a sockets guide.

```
import socket
import select
import sys
import gtk

if len (sys.argv) > 1:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
else:
    filename = ''

class MyApp():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        win = gtk.Window()
        win.set_size_request(320,200)
        win.connect('destroy',gtk.main_quit)
        tv = gtk.TextView()
        self.buff = tv.get_buffer()
        win.add(tv)
        win.show_all()
        self.open_file()
        # This timeout runs check_for_file every 200ms
        gtk.timeout_add(200, self.check_for_file)

    def check_for_file(self):
        """
        Check if filename is waiting to be read from the socket
        open file if it is
        """
        readable,writeable,inerror = select.select([serversock],[],[],0)
        if len (readable) > 0:
            client,addr = serversock.accept()
            self.filename = client.recv(1024)
            self.open_file()
        # Must always return 'True', or the timeout loop will stop.
        return(True)

    def open_file(self):
        """Dummy function, prints filename to open"""
        self.buff.insert_at_cursor('Opening file {}\n'.format(self.filename))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    Try to open connection to a socket. If successfull, app is already
    running, send filename to it and quit.
    If unsuccessful, app is NOT running, open a listening socket and run
    app.
    """
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.connect(('localhost',4689))
    except socket.error:
        serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serversock.bind(('localhost',4689))
        serversock.listen(2)
    else:
        sock.send(filename)
        sock.close()
        sys.exit()

    app = MyApp(filename)
    gtk.main()
    serversock.close()
```